# kstream topology with inmemory statestore data not commited

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to aggregate client information and every hours push it to an output topic.

I have a topology with :

- input-topic
- processor
- sink topic

Data arrives in input-topic with a key in string which contains a clientID concatenated with date in YYYYMMDDHH
.
In my processor I use a simple `InMemoryKeyValueStore` (withCachingDisabled) to merge/aggregate data with specific rules (data are sometime not aggregated according to business logic).

In a `punctuator`, every hours the program parse the statestore to get all the messages transform it and `forward` it to the sink topic, after what I clean the statestore for all the message processed.

After the punctuation, I ask the size of the store which is effectivly  empty (by `.all()` and
`approximateNumEntries`), every thing is **OK**.

But when I restart the application, the statstore is restored with all the elements normally deleted.

When I parse manually (with a simple `KafkaConsumer`) the changelog topic of the statestore in Kafka, I view that I have two records for each key :

- The first record is commited and the message contains my aggregation.
- The second record is a deletion message (message with null) **but is not commited** (visible only with `read_uncommitted`) which is dangerous in my case because the next punctuator will forward again the aggregate.

I have play with commit in the punctuator which forward, I have create an other punctuator which commit the context periodically (every 3 seconds) but after the restart I still have my data restored in the store (normal my delete message in not commited.)

I have a classic kstream configuration :

```
acks=all
enable.idempotence=true
processing.guarantee=exactly_once_v2
commit.interval.ms=100
isolation.level=read_committed
```

with the last version of the library  `kafka-streams 3.2.2` and a `cluster in 2.6`

Any help is welcome to have my record in the statestore commited. I don't use `TimeWindowedKStream` which is not exactly my need (sometime I don't aggregate but directly forward)

Comment: It seems that `datastore.flush()` can be part of the solution.

Comment: Interesting, I have very similar application, which also removes data from state store after some time and I've just checked the _changelog topic with `--isolation-level=read_committed` and deleting message with null value is there. Code of this application is here https://github.com/pszymczyk/kafka-streams-playground/tree/master/src/main/java/com/pszymczyk/app8